# Python - How do I push out 50k messages via AMQP lib to RabbitMQ efficiently?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, python-3.4

Here is my MQ class:

```
import amqp as amqp

class MQ():

    mqConn = None
    channel = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        if self.mqConn is None:
            self.mqConn = amqp.Connection(host="localhost", userid="dev", password="dev", virtual_host="/", insist=False)
            self.channel = self.mqConn.channel()

        elif not self.mqConn.connected:
            self.mqConn = amqp.Connection(host="localhost", userid="dev", password="dev", virtual_host="/", insist=False)
            self.channel = self.mqConn.channel()

    def sendMQ(self, message):
        self.connect()
        lMessage = amqp.Message(message)
        self.channel.basic_publish(lMessage, exchange="DevMatrixE", routing_key="dev_matrix_q")
```

I then call the sendMQ() function 50,000 times to push the messages to the RabbitMQ server. It takes a little over 5 seconds to complete. That's around 10k messages per second, which unfortunately is too slow for my needs. Is there a more efficient way to feed all 50,000 messages into the server? I know the server itself can handle a lot more messages incoming, but I think my bottleneck is on the basic_publish.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code to see exactly where the time is spent? That's probably a good first step to work out what needs to be optimised. Alternatively, you might want to look at the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: Do you mean profiling the amqp library itself? But from my code's perspective its exactly at the basic_publish that's taking 10ms per function call which explains 10k messages per second. I thought multiprocessing is slow to create the threads, so it would actually hurt the situation since its a very short piece of code its executing per call? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what multiprocessing does. Could you write a sample code for my above example?

Comment: Ref multiprocessing, take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: Ref the 10ms per publish, it looks like you're using a blocking connection. If that's the case, have a look at https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/adapters/select.html (you might want to use Pika).

Comment: If you want to push as many messages as possible you probably want to use the C based library librabbitmq instead, but even with librabbitmq you will need to have 2-3 processes running to get that kind of throughput.

Comment: What is the avg message size? I publish 50K messages in less that 4sec if their size is max 10KB (using pika 0.9.5, BlockingConnection).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send a huge amount of messages in a short period of time, using the C based library [librabbitmq](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/librabbitmq) should be able to get you there. Keep in mind that performance it will depend on the latency on your network connection.

I ran the following very simple example sending 50k messages based on [librabbitmq](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/librabbitmq) on my local VM and it finished in just under 0.4 seconds.

```
import time

from librabbitmq import Connection

conn = Connection(host="localhost", userid="guest",
                  password="guest", virtual_host="/")
channel = conn.channel()

start_time = time.time()
for _ in xrange(50000):
    channel.basic_publish('This is a test payload!', '', 'simple_queue')

print time.time() - start_time
```

**Output**

```
eandersson@eu-dev-rabbitmq01:~$ python test.py
0.384150981903
```

I tried it using my own library, [AMQP-Storm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amqp-storm), but I get about the same time as you did with py-amqp, 4-5 seconds to send 50k messages.

Another solution would be to use a different Python implementation; such as PyPy. PyPy performs much better with the Python native AMQP libraries.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! - I am actually using Python 3.4. Is there a version of it that works with the later versions of Python?

Comment: No C version that works in Python 3.X yet unfortunately. With Python 3.X your only option will be to scale your operations using multiprocessing.

Comment: You could make a separate microservice in Python 2 and have the two talk to each other over a socket.

Comment: I have ported my code to be complaint with Python 2.7, but unforunately it looks like librabbitmq does not support Windows. - Any further ideas on something else I can use on a Windows/Python 2.7 environment, that is fast?

Comment: Is it even possible for someone to compile librabbitmq for me? Could that possibly work?

Comment: It looks like the windows supported flag was added by mistake, but the author also said that he didn't see a reason why it couldn't be compiled for windows, just that he does not have the expertise required.

Comment: Yeah spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to compile the code but to no avail. Going to try using Pika instead with the SelectConnection. - I have no idea how to implement it so it works with my code though. Mind taking a look at the related question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332320/how-to-do-a-simple-pika-selectconnection-to-send-a-message-in-python

Comment: Haven't really used the SelectConnection so not to much help there. I did however try using my library with amqp-storm and PyPy and with those you can send 50k messages in 2.5s. http://pypy.org/download.html